# Inconsistent behavior of Limit function when evaluating a directed limit at a discontinuity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, discontinuity

Consider the following expression:

```
(* In *) expr1 = Hold[Limit[Sign[x], x -> y, Direction -> "FromAbove"] == Sign[y]]
```

Now let's substitute a specific value to `y`:

```
(* In *) expr2 = expr1 /. y -> 0
```

If I now evaluate it I get inconsistent results:

```
(* In *) ReleaseHold[expr1]
(* Out *) True
(* In *) ReleaseHold[expr2]
(* Out *) False
```

In my opinion, `expr1` is wrongly evaluated. I suppose that the `Limit` function somehow "forgets" about the special case being possible for `y == 0` which leads to this problem. How could I avoid this? I would expect to get something like the following for `Limit[Sign[x], x -> y, Direction -> "FromAbove"]` as a correct result:

```
(* Out *) Piecewise[{{Sign[y], y != 0}, {1, y == 0}}]
```

Comment: Even using `GenerateConditions -> True` doesn't yield the correct answer for the limit `"FromAbove`". I believe this is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [`GenerateConditions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GenerateConditions.html) option for `Limit`, like so:

```
limit = Limit[Sign[x], x -> y, GenerateConditions -> True]
(* ConditionalExpression[Sign[y], y != 0] *)

limit /. y -> 0
(* Undefined *)
```

This works with many symbolic functions. In my opinion, it should default to `True` across the board, but the current default is `Automatic`, which does different things with different functions.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this will have to do, but I am still not completely happy with it since the directed limit is actually defined at y=0 and that information is not included in the input.

Comment: Oh, I see. I forgot that option and the answer is still wrong! I'll mark it as a bug.